# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/WEB-INF/spring-form.tld" not found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

hi I am using Spring mvc, servlet, jsp, oracle i am getting this error:'org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/WEB-INF/spring-form.tld" not found' can anybody tell me how to fix this
my jsp page looks like

**ContactForm.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %> --%>

   

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
        <h1>New/Edit Contact</h1>
        <form:form action="saveContact" method="post" modelAttribute="contact">
        <table>
            <form:hidden path="id"/>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telephone:</td>
                <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

tld file and place in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: download spring-tld file and place in your WEB-INF folder

Comment: also download spring-form.tld

Comment: after including the both jar it says form:from tag can find

Answer (score 0):

Download Jar : spring-webmvc-3.0.x.RELEASE.jar and put it in your build path or if you are working with maven project, add below entry in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This jar contains Spring form tag libs.

Comment: Try putting <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
 in your JSP file

Comment: Can not find the tag library descriptor for "springframework.org/tags"